# how keras solves these questions relative task?

Tags: keras

There are 2 relative questions.

all 2 question has multiple answers .

```
question1: please mark the brands you know below

a)bland1 b)bland2 c)bland3 d)bland4
```

If user marked a) and c),then the result array is[1,0,1,0]

```
question2: please mark the brands you have bought below

a)bland1  c)bland3
```

If user marked a), then the result array is `[1,Nan,0,Nan]` (the b,and d, will not show up because bland2 and bland 4 is not selected in qestion 1).
So the final array is

```
[[1,0,1,0],
[1,Nan,0,Nan]]
```

I want to generate 1000 records by using prediction, I need generated data is obey to the rule, however result is bad, acc is only 0.25

```
_m = Sequential()

_m.add(Dense(5000,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)),)

_m.add(Dense(500,activation='relu'))

_m.add(Dense(len(outs),activation='sigmoid'))

_m.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=
['accuracy'])

_m.fit(x_train,y_train, batch_size=100,epochs=1000,verbose=0)

score = _m.evaluate(x_test,y_test,100)
```

Please help to improve it, should i use `lstm`?

Comment: btw, if i use 0 to replace all NaN, the acc will increase to 0.78, but i have to keep the Nan value

Answer (score 0):

Putting `Nan` makes no sense. You should replace it by 0. You may incorrectly use `outs`.  I will suggest to design outs as the combination of the two questions as follows: i.e. knowing

- Ans to Q1 is [a1, b1, c1, d1]
- Ans to Q2 is [a2, b2, c2, d2]

then outs should be [2^a1+a2, 2^b1+b2, 2^c1+c2, 2^d1+d2].

In other words, your model will produces a ternary classification instead of binary.

Whether or not using a LSTM depends on your input: is it time sequence data, or can be viewed as a time sequence.

Comment: thank pitfall point the solution, i still have some question on it. 1)because 0 and none have different meanings, so should i replace none to 2 or other int? 2)since it will be a ternary problem as you suggest, should i change the loss to categorical_crossentropy and last activation to softmax?